# Xamarin round cornered frame's background color surpasses the rounded edges

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm using a frame tag to wrap a grid inside, but whenever I add corner radius to the frame, the background color of the said frame goes out from the rounded corners and is displayed as a sharp corner.

Can anyone help?

An image is also attached with the question to portray the problem correctly.

The code snippet is:

```
<Frame CornerRadius="15" 
       BackgroundColor="Aqua"  
       OutlineColor="Black" 
       MinimumHeightRequest="100" 
       MinimumWidthRequest="150" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       Grid.Column="2">
    <Grid x:Name="MessageGrid"   
          HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
          VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" 
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
              InputTransparent="True"  
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="InfoText" 
                   TextColor="Black" 
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                   InputTransparent="True"
                   Text="Tooltip text goes here and this is to check if its responsive"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

[image]

Comment: UWP Bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56914 Works as expected on iOS/Android (at least with Forms `2.5.0.91635`

Comment: I've got this problem too. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Did you try setting your Frames IsClippedToBounds="True".

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in the implementation of the Frame element type.  Although a frame won't contain it's own background, it will contain the backgrounds of other elements within it.

The work-around is to wrap one frame inside an identical sized frame. Use the outer frame to specify the CornerRadius, but leave out the BackgroundColor.  The inner frame can specify the background color and it will be rounded off by the outer frame.

Be sure to include Padding="0,0,0,0" on both frames.

Comment: only need to have the Padding="0,0,0,0" on the outer frame though.  but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply set:

```
IsClippedToBounds = "True"
```

in frame. It will stop child element to go outside of container.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the FreshEssentials library. See

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57546/how-can-i-achieve-this-effect-stacklayout-or-frame

and

http://michaelridland.com/xamarin/freshessentials-for-xamarin-forms-the-must-have-nuget-for-forms/

Answer (score 0):

it is because you frame allows your grid to go out of its bound so you need to set is clip to bounds `IsClippedToBounds = "True"`

after applying this in to your code it will look like this

```
<Frame CornerRadius="15" 
       BackgroundColor="Aqua"  
       OutlineColor="Black" 
       MinimumHeightRequest="100" 
       MinimumWidthRequest="150" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       Grid.Column="2"
       IsClippedToBounds = "True">
    <Grid x:Name="MessageGrid"   
          HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
          VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" 
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
              InputTransparent="True"  
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="InfoText" 
                   TextColor="Black" 
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                   InputTransparent="True"
                   Text="Tooltip text goes here and this is to check if its responsive"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

now when you set `IsClippedToBounds = "True"` it will tell your frame to not let its child elements go out of its bounds/borders so your issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was hard to fix it. But, I found the solution:
I created a property called EntryBackgroundColorProperty and, inside Custom Renderer implementation, the color of gradientDrawabe was pointed to this new property.

To summarize: you must avoid use the default property "BackgroundColor", create another instead.